# Mootools class display none

Tags: class, mootools, toggle

I need your help.
I have divs like that.

```
<div class="blue red green"></div>
<div class="blue green"></div>
<div class="blue"></div>
```

Now i want make a filter.
Its not hard do set by click toggle class blue.
Filter looks like that

(x) blue (x) red (x) green

But if its possible to say. If there are more than class blue 
in it dont toggle and if its possible that when class blue and green are disable
than toogle the second div.

Found this Jquery is that possible with mootools?
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/creating-a-filterable-portfolio-with-jquery/

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find element with only class "blue"

`$$('.blue')`

To find element wit class "blue" and "green"

`$$('.blue.green')`

To find elements with "blue" or "green" you cab just search two times.